# Applescript 10.7:Can’t get anchor "FileVault" of pane id "com.apple.preference.security"

Tags: macos, applescript, osx-lion

I am trying to access the "FileVault" Tab using Applescript. Can someone help me out?

This is where I am getting the error:

```
reveal anchor "FileVault" of pane id "com.apple.preference.security"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the anchor has a different name internally:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    get every anchor of pane id "com.apple.preference.security"
        --> {anchor "Firewall" of pane id "com.apple.preference.security",
             anchor "FDE" of pane id "com.apple.preference.security",
             anchor "General" of pane id "com.apple.preference.security",
             anchor "Privacy" of pane id "com.apple.preference.security"}
end tell
```

I suspect that the "FileVault" anchor was reserved for the old home-directory-only File Vault encryption settings, which only show up (as "Legacy FileVault", iirc?) if you're still using that scheme.

Comment: How to go a step forword to reveal Privacy > Accessibility directly from this script ?

Comment: @PiyushMathur `anchor "Privacy_Assistive"`.

Comment: @duskwuff Tried Accessibility instead of Assistive, it worked on both Mavericks and Yosemite. Thanks man.